# How to choose a value of a field based on conditions given in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have fields like DayEndinventory,Daysales and reorderlevel.

I have to calculate Daysales:

I have 2 conditions for that:

if  my   `dayendinventory < reorder level*4` then take value of reorderlevel as Daysales
else I have to choose the value of `DayEndInventory` as Daysales

How do I do that?

Comment: Please add sample data and the expected output to your question.  Even if someone (like Gordon) can venture an answer, adding data would make your question more useful to other readers in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [case expression](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm):

```
select
    case when (dayendinventory < reorder_level*4) then reorderlevel 
         else DayEndInventory
    end as Daysales 
from table
```